# Ampersand Placement in a Parameter

Tags: c++, reference

I'm new to C++ and am learning about the Reference Operator and how it works. Will the placement of the operator & make a difference whether it be in front of or at the back of the variable? For example:

```
MenuCalories&
&MenuCalories
```

This is a Header file to be used in the source code and I'm just trying to understand it

```
class MenuCalories {
  private:
    unsigned int* calories;
    size_t num;

  public:
    // constructors (default, one arg, and copy)
    MenuCalories();
    MenuCalories( unsigned int numberOfMenuItems);
    MenuCalories( const MenuCalories& original);

    // destructor
    ~MenuCalories();

    // Member function
    int calorieAtIndex( int index );
};
```

I'm assuming that the contents of `MenuCalories` wont be changing but idk what the original does.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `MenuCalories& MenuCalories` is the same as `MenuCalories &MenuCalories` but both are different from `MenuCalories& &MenuCalories`. The last one is invalid.  You can use `MenuCalories&& MenuCalories`,  which  is valid but still different than the first two.

Comment: In this context `&` is not an operator it's a type modifier (that might not be the technically correct term). It's similar to the `*` you use to declare a pointer, only it declares a reference. So `const MenuCalories& original` is a parameter called `original` whose type is a reference to a constant `MenuCalories` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The & token is used for two purposes, One to create reference variable and Second to get memory address of a variable. 
When it is used at LHS of assignment, like
int &a=b;
Then a reference to variable b is created. When you use it in function signature, it interpret the same.
void fun(int &b); 
When you use & at RHS of assignment, it will give address of variable. Like
int *p=&q;

& Operator is used in front of variable, and according to the statement in which it occur, it will convey its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The & token is used for three purposes, One to create reference variable, Second to get memory address of a variable, and Third as Bitwise AND operator.

The & is placed just after the datatype to indicate that we are creating reference type variable of the same type. Here it work as Type Modifier. 
For example: int& b=a; or void func(int& b);

When you use & at RHS of assignment, it will give address of variable. Like
int *p=&q;

& Operator is used in front of variable, and according to the statement in which it occur, it will convey its meaning. Placing it after variable name does not mean anything.